# Class Access Variable

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've written out a template of what the basic code I'm trying to figure out is based on so you don't need to sift through it

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class class1 {

int main()
{
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Just call it: `instanceOfClass2.print();` Of course, you need an instance of `class2` in hand.

Comment: I have to access class2's print() with a class1 instance using class1's accessclass2

Comment: Imagine that you are somehow able to call `class2::print` without specifying a particular instance of `class2` on which to call it. What exactly do you expect such a call to print? What should be the value of `y` within `class2::print`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do it the the exact declaration order in your post you can do this with a forward declaration. This will allow you to declare `accessclass2` to take an instance of `class2` as an argument without knowing the details. You will simply need to define `accessclass2` after `class2` has been defined.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//  Forward declaration allows you to pass a reference to the function withing
//  having the details of the class2 yet.
class class2;


class class1
{
public:
    int x;
    class1()
    {
        x = 0;
    }
    void accessclass2(class2& other);
};


class class2 {
public:
    int y;
    class2()
    {
        y = 10;
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << y << endl;
    }
};

void class1::accessclass2(class2& other)
{
    other.print();
}

int main()
{
    class1 foo;
    class2 bar;

    foo.accessclass2(bar);
    return 0;

}
```